# How to Construct $N$-dimensional Unitary Matrix Basis

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, quantum-mechanics

Galitski's *Exploring Quantum Mechanics* says on its page 29,

> (There are $N^2$ linearly) independent Hermitian matrices of rank $N$. The number of independent unitary matrices is also $N^2$, since there is a relation between them and Hermitian matrices $U=\text{exp}(iF).$

As I understand how to construct the Hermitian basis of $F^{n\times n}$ with 'standard basis' matrices $E_{ij}$, I understand the first half of the statement. But is the relation $U=\text{exp}(iF)$ relevant? How can I construct a unitary basis from the given Hermitian basis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $E_{i,j}$ are matrix units, i.e. what you call the 'standard basis', you can define $U_{i,j} = \exp(i E_{i,j})$. These are $N^2$ unitary matrices. It is a good exercise to write out an explicit formula for them. The claim is that $U_{i,j}$ are also linearly independent, which you should be able to easily verify.

Note though that the book is talking about matrices of **rank $N$**, while the matrix units have rank 1. So you want to consider $\mathbb{1}+E_{i,j}$ instead, and check that everything still works as claimed.